# How can I make nginx redirect subdomain to a folder?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, reverse

How can I make nginx redirect all the requests to my subdomain to a folder?

Example:

http://sub2.sub1.domain.com/

that should indicate that sub2 is a folder in sub1.domain.com/sub2

How can I do this?

The main objective is to hide the folder to the user. So, it should continue as
http://sub2.sub1.domain.com/

My wish is to use a wildcard in sub2.

UPDATE:

I've tried:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name ~^(.*)\.sis\..*$;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://sis.mydomain.com/$1$request_uri;
    }
}
```

but it also didn't work, any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `nginx` directives for `sub2.sub1.domain.com` you'd put:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub2.sub1.domain.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass https://sub1.domain.com/sub2;
    }
}
```

So any request going to `sub2.sub1.domain.com` gets proxied to → `sub1.domain.com/sub2` (while masked as sub2.sub1.domain.com); no need for a redirect or rewrite this way either.

**Wildcard Method**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(.*)\.sub1\.domain\.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass https://sub1.domain.com/$1;
    }
}
```

<sub>*the wildcard method above is untested.</sub>

Comment: Is there any way to use it with a wildcard in sub2?

Comment: @user3249427: See edit. I'm assuming you mean `*.sub1.domain.com` gets proxied to `sub1.domain.com/*`.